# Binding to AssemblyVersion in XAML (for Help/About dialogue)

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml

Maybe I'm expecting too much here, but I figure I can't be the first person to have tried. Do I have to create (yet another) converter for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Accessing the current assembly's version requires method calls, so you can't do it with WPF binding:

```
Version version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
```

Either use a converter (as you suggest), or create a property on your view model (as Kent suggests).

Comment: Thanks, in the end I mixed and match - a property directly in my window (MVVM will be for later)

Answer (score 6):

Not if you're using MVVM. Just expose a Version property from your view model and bind to that.